# Uncaught TypeError: $jq.sessionTimeoutTwo is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have declared a function sessionTimeoutTwo between script tags.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
  $jq(document).ready(function() {
    alert('called');
    $jq.sessionTimeoutTwo({
    title: 'Session Timeout Warning',
    message: 'Your session is about to expire in exactly:',
    warnAfter: 3000,
    redirAfter: 8000,
    keepAliveUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
    redirUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
    logoutUrl: 'http://www.google.com'
    });
  }

  //this is the function definition
  (function ($) {
    jQuery.sessionTimeoutTwo = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            title: 'Session Timeout',
            message: 'Your session is about to expire in: ',
            keepAliveUrl: '/keep-alive',
            redirUrl: '/timed-out',
            logoutUrl: '/log-out',
            warnAfter: 900000, // 15 minutes
            redirAfter: 1200000 // 20 minutes
        };

        // Extend user-set options over defaults
        var o = defaults;

        if (options) {
            o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        }
        var latestActivity = new Date();
        var count=o.redirAfter/1000;
        var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000)
        resetOnUser();
        checkActivity();


        // Create timeout warning dialog
        $('body').append('<div title="' 
                         + o.title 
                         + '" id="sessionTimeout-dialog"><p>' 
                         + o.message 
                         + '</p><span id="sessionTimeout-timer"></span>&nbsp;seconds.</div>');
        $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            open: function () {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            },
            buttons: {
                // Button one - takes user to logout URL
                "Log Out Now": function () {
                    window.location = o.logoutUrl;
                },
                // Button two - closes dialog and makes call to keep-alive URL
                "Stay Connected": function () {
                    latestActivity = new Date();
                    $(this).dialog('close');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: o.keepAliveUrl
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        function resetOnUser() {
            $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                latestActivity = new Date();
            });
            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                latestActivity = new Date();
            });
        }

        function elapsed() {
            return (new Date() - latestActivity);
        }

        function checkActivity() {
            var check = setInterval(

            function () {
                if (elapsed() > o.warnAfter) {
                    $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog('open');
                }
                if (elapsed() > o.redirAfter) {
                    window.location = o.redirUrl;
                }

            }, 3000);
        }

        function timer()  {
          count=count-1;
          if (count <= 0)
          {
             clearInterval(counter);             
             return;
          }

          $("#sessionTimeout-timer").html(count);
          }
    };
  })(jQuery); 
</script>
```

It is displaying the alert.
After that at the function call I'm getting the below error.
**Uncaught TypeError: $jq.sessionTimeoutTwo is not a function.**
I added **jQuery.noConflict();** also. 
But still getting the error.
Could you help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code in which you have defined function `sessionTimeoutTwo()` at the top and then you can make successful call to it later.

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

//this is the function definition
(function ($) {
  jQuery.sessionTimeoutTwo = function (options) {
      console.log('Entering sessionTimeoutTwo function');
      var defaults = {
          title: 'Session Timeout',
          message: 'Your session is about to expire in: ',
          keepAliveUrl: '/keep-alive',
          redirUrl: '/timed-out',
          logoutUrl: '/log-out',
          warnAfter: 900000, // 15 minutes
          redirAfter: 1200000 // 20 minutes
      };

      // Extend user-set options over defaults
      var o = defaults;

      if (options) {
          o = $.extend(defaults, options);
      }
      var latestActivity = new Date();
      var count=o.redirAfter/1000;
      var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000)
      resetOnUser();
      checkActivity();


      // Create timeout warning dialog
      $('body').append('<div title="' 
                       + o.title 
                       + '" id="sessionTimeout-dialog"><p>' 
                       + o.message 
                       + '</p><span id="sessionTimeout-timer"></span>&nbsp;seconds.</div>');
      $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          width: 400,
          modal: true,
          closeOnEscape: false,
          open: function () {
              $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
          },
          buttons: {
              // Button one - takes user to logout URL
              "Log Out Now": function () {
                  window.location = o.logoutUrl;
              },
              // Button two - closes dialog and makes call to keep-alive URL
              "Stay Connected": function () {
                  latestActivity = new Date();
                  $(this).dialog('close');

                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: o.keepAliveUrl
                  });
              }
          }
      });

      function resetOnUser() {
          $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
              latestActivity = new Date();
          });
          $(this).keypress(function (e) {
              latestActivity = new Date();
          });
      }

      function elapsed() {
          return (new Date() - latestActivity);
      }

      function checkActivity() {
          var check = setInterval(

          function () {
              if (elapsed() > o.warnAfter) {
                  $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog('open');
              }
              if (elapsed() > o.redirAfter) {
                  window.location = o.redirUrl;
              }

          }, 3000);
      }

      function timer()  {
        count=count-1;
        if (count <= 0)
        {
           clearInterval(counter);             
           return;
        }

        $("#sessionTimeout-timer").html(count);
        }
  };
})(jQuery); 

$jq(document).ready(function() {
    alert('called');
        $jq.sessionTimeoutTwo({
        title: 'Session Timeout Warning',
        message: 'Your session is about to expire in exactly:',
        warnAfter: 3000,
        redirAfter: 8000,
        keepAliveUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
        redirUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
        logoutUrl: 'http://www.google.com'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user2636874 - It's not the `same error`. See I have added log and it is entering your function `sessionTimeoutTwo `. The current error for `.dialog` function. For that you need to add - https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js this file. See Edit.

Comment: yes your are right. It is not showing an error after adding the above script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function which has not been loaded to DOM yet, that is the reason you need to put your function definition before document ready.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
 // var sessionTimeoutTwo;
  (function ($) {
    jQuery.sessionTimeoutTwo = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            title: 'Session Timeout',
            message: 'Your session is about to expire in: ',
            keepAliveUrl: '/keep-alive',
            redirUrl: '/timed-out',
            logoutUrl: '/log-out',
            warnAfter: 900000, // 15 minutes
            redirAfter: 1200000 // 20 minutes
        };

        // Extend user-set options over defaults
        var o = defaults;

        if (options) {
            o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        }
        var latestActivity = new Date();
        var count=o.redirAfter/1000;
        var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000)
        resetOnUser();
        checkActivity();


        // Create timeout warning dialog
        $('body').append('<div title="' 
                         + o.title 
                         + '" id="sessionTimeout-dialog"><p>' 
                         + o.message 
                         + '</p><span id="sessionTimeout-timer"></span>&nbsp;seconds.</div>');


        function resetOnUser() {
            $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                latestActivity = new Date();
            });
            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                latestActivity = new Date();
            });
        }

        function elapsed() {
            return (new Date() - latestActivity);
        }

        function checkActivity() {
            var check = setInterval(

            function () {
                if (elapsed() > o.warnAfter) {
                    $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog('open');
                }
                if (elapsed() > o.redirAfter) {
                    window.location = o.redirUrl;
                }

            }, 3000);
        }

        function timer()  {
          count=count-1;
          if (count <= 0)
          {
             clearInterval(counter);             
             return;
          }

          $("#sessionTimeout-timer").html(count);
          }
    };
  })(jQuery);
  $jq(document).ready(function() {
    alert('called');
    $jq.sessionTimeoutTwo({
    title: 'Session Timeout Warning',
    message: 'Your session is about to expire in exactly:',
    warnAfter: 3000,
    redirAfter: 8000,
    keepAliveUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
    redirUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
    logoutUrl: 'http://www.google.com'
    });
    $jq('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            open: function () {
                $jq(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            },
            buttons: {
                // Button one - takes user to logout URL
                "Log Out Now": function () {
                    window.location = '/log-out';
                },
                // Button two - closes dialog and makes call to keep-alive URL
                "Stay Connected": function () {
                    latestActivity = new Date();
                    $jq(this).dialog('close');

                    $jq.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/keep-alive'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
  }
  ); 
</script>
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qaoyru7m/3/) .